# create a div with a text where i click an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image in HTML and i want the user to write an input in HTML and then if he click on the image it will create a colored `div` which is written inside the `input`, the position of this `div` is based of the coordinates where the user clicked (not centered, a little on top and to the left), for now I can create the rectangular `div`, but i don't know how to put a text in it.

```js
let listaAre = [];
let quantiClic = 0;

document.getElementById('blah').addEventListener('click', event => {
  document.getElementById('squareContaine').innerHTML =
    document.getElementById('squareContaine').innerHTML +
    '<div id="squar' + quantiClic + '" style="background-color: blue; height: 50px; width: 50px; position: absolute;"></div>';
  document.getElementById('squar' + quantiClic).style.top = (event.pageY - Number(document.getElementById('dimensione').value) / 2) + 'px';
  document.getElementById('squar' + quantiClic).style.left = (event.pageX - Number(document.getElementById('dimensione').value) / 2) + 'px';
  document.getElementById('squar' + quantiClic).style.width = Number(document.getElementById('dimensione').value)/4 + 'px';
  document.getElementById('squar' + quantiClic).style.height = Number(document.getElementById('dimensione').value)/10 + 'px';
  document.getElementById('squar' + quantiClic).style.background =(document.getElementById('colorebordo').value);

  listaAre.push({
    x: (event.offsetX - Number(document.getElementById('dimensione').value) / 2),
    y: (event.offsetY - Number(document.getElementById('dimensione').value) / 2),
    width: Number(document.getElementById('dimensione').value),
    height: Number(document.getElementById('dimensione').value),
    background:(document.getElementById('colorebordo').value)
  });
  document.getElementById('squar' + quantiClic).addEventListener('click',       function (e) {
    this.style.display = 'none';
  });
  quantiClic = quantiClic + 1;
});
```

```css
article, aside, figure, footer, header,
hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
.fasciaalta {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="fasciaalta">
  <input type="color" id="colorebordo">
  <input type="text" id="nome">
  <input type="number" id="dimensione" value="200">
  <hr size="2px" color="blue" width="100">
</div>

<img id="blah" src="montagna.jpg" alt="your image" />
<div id="squareContaine"></div>

<div id="previewImage"></div>
```

Comment: is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/3kjqfh6x/1/

Comment: the problem is that the text need to be inside the colored div and both of them should appear when and where the user click on the image and not when clicking a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the coordinates of the mouse on the event click by accessing the `clientX` and `clientY` properties of the event object. Then you simply tell the new element to use them as top and left styles to position it.

#### Snippet

```js
document.getElementById('blah').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var div = document.createElement("DIV"); // Create a <div> element
  var t = document.createTextNode("HELLO");// Create a text node
  div.appendChild(t);                      // Append the text to <div>

  document.body.appendChild(div);          //Add <div> to document
  div.style.position = 'absolute';         //Make its position absolute

  //Set the coordinates
  div.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
  div.style.top  = event.clientY + "px";
})
```

```html
<div>
<img id="blah" src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb6/nyancat/images/5/50/Wiki-background" alt="your image" />
</div>
```

#### Extra

If instead of creating a new div, you want to use one simply access that element with `getElementById` and change its properties instead. I've made the example as simple as possible so that it can apply to not only your case but anyone else's trying to solve their issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the text value then all you need is to change the first 2 statements of your click function. - [Check this Codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/qawZar)

1) Onclick, get the value of the textbox like so

```
var val = document.getElementById('nome').value;
```

2) Next insert this `val` into your `innerHTML` statement

```
document.getElementById('squareContaine').innerHTML =
document.getElementById('squareContaine').innerHTML +
'<div id="squar' + quantiClic + '" style="background-color: blue; height: 50px; width: 50px; position: absolute;">'+ val + '</div>';
```

Scroll the very end of the above statement to see the `val` inserted.

> Also do not forget to change the color of the text if the background of the box is black.

```
  document.getElementById('blah').addEventListener('click', event => {
    var val = document.getElementById('nome').value; //added
    //below statement changed
    document.getElementById('squareContaine').innerHTML =
    document.getElementById('squareContaine').innerHTML +
    '<div id="squar' + quantiClic + '" style="background-color: blue; height: 50px; width: 50px; position: absolute;">'+ val + '</div>';

    .. rest of the code remain the same ..
  });
```